# Loading screen Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to change default loading screen when i navigate between pages on WP8 app but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is many ways of doing it and you need to address what exactly is your best solution.

So the splash screen is the first place to start, here you can specify images that should be used upon start the app. It is also possible to introduce animations.

Your case (As far as I understand) is referring to navigation in-app. Again here I assume you use Silverlight, and not Win-RT?

For this you can create either popups or change the PhoneApplicationFrame. Popups can be displayed across pages during navigation. This however has the issue with memory leak and low performance, because of the popup implementation in WP.

I would therefore go with changing the PhoneApplicationFrame, you can follow this: [Specify Popup location, throughout page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622665/specify-popup-location-throughout-page-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Very little information about you app, but maybe this will help:[How to create a custom indeterminate progress bar for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg442303(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Addingacustomindeterminateprogressbar)